# What is the difference between "patron"and "customer"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

As the result I looked them up, the word "patron" means a regular customer. Sometimes, they are overlapped. For example, I can say

> "The more 'customers' or 'patrons' in the restaurant will cause the slower serving the foods."

In this case, they are interchangeable. Is it correct?

Comment: both are fine... [patron=customer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/patron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms are not always interchangeable. Fast food restaurants may have customers, but upscale restaurants have patrons.

I worked at a university library once. On one of my first days I told a more experienced worker, there's a customer here with a question. They raised their eyebrows and told me, "you mean a patron. Libraries don't have customers."

And I think that applies to other places. The store [Target](http://m.target.com/) does not refer to the people shopping there as customers  but as 'guests'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to ***patron***'s definition in [cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/patron), both 'patron' and 'customer' are synonyms of each other and can be used interchangeably in this example:

> The more 'customers' or 'patrons' in the restaurant will cause the slower serving the foods.

Mostly, for restaurants and shops, a 'patron' is considered as a 'regular customer' Check [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patron) entry.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in both restaurants and in cinemas and what I had explained to me was with Patrons as compared to Customers - Patrons don't take away anything from the business (except for a full stomach or imagination!) but customers physically take goods away from the business. I would be interested if this was correct or not.